# asp.net core web api Post form data with brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm running server build with asp.net core (v2.1) web api and have this REST HTTP call:

```
POST http://website.com/callback
```

with the headers:

```
...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and the body:

```
response%5Bkey%5D=123&response%5Bname%5D=hi
```

I want to receive this message at this point:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("callbacks")]
public ActionResult Hook([FromForm]Model model)
{
    // <---- Model has instance but empty fields
    return Ok();
}
```

My Model is:

```
public class Model
{
    public string key { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Somehow the brackets ("[key]" and "[name]") are not being parsed into my model instance. They are null both, although I provide them in body.

How to solve it?

Comment: why is the body so strange? How you submit the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set name in form for your properties:

```
public class Model
{
    [FromForm(Name = "response[key]")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "response[name]")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```